# how to visualize/graphically display org-mode files for brainstorming editing?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, mind-mapping, opml, omnioutliner

I use MindNode Pro OSX for brainstorming. I prefer it to Freemind for its ease of use and its prettiness, factors which help me think and be creative.

I'm trying to switch to plain text in all my documents. I used to use OmniOutliner, but I found that the .oo3/.OPML markup cluttered my files and made it hard to find things and visualize keywords and their textual context via full-text search.

I assume that Emacs org-mode is the best text-based tool for brainstorming/outlining. How can I interoperate, going back and forth between an org-mode text file and a MindNode Pro visualization mind map, so that I can go back and forth using each in turn interchangeably to edit as I brainstorm, write, and add ideas?

Or, is there an alternative to MindNode that would allow me to do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a simple Python script that converts Emacs Org mode files to OPML format that can be opened in Mindnode. Have a look.

https://github.com/semk/Org2OPML

http://foobarnbaz.com/2013/08/02/awesome-mindmaps-using-org/